# Replace a Router routee with an Actor of the same type

Tags: scala, akka

I am using a `akka.routing.Router` actor to broadcast a `Work` to different kind of actors. I use a `akka.routing.BroadcastRoutingLogic` to have this behaviour. The `Router` contains one single actor of each type (`Type1Actor` does job 1 with `Work`, `Type2Actor` does job 2 with the same `Work`...).

When an actor is terminated (no matter how) I receive a :

```
def receive = {
 //...
 case Terminated(a) => //HERE DO SOMETHING
}
```

I want to update my routees to always keep the same amount of active actors and to have the same amount of active actors of a type. 
The type of `Terminated` actor is important : I don't want a work to be done twice by two actors of the same type, I don't want a work not to be done by an actor `TypeXActor`.

Is there a way to retrieve the appropriate `Props` from a terminated ref (`a` here) ? If not what are my options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Name your workers

Name your workers and then retrieve the name to decide the type of the actor

```
val router: ActorRef =
  context.actorOf(BroadcastPool(5).props(Props(new Worker(), "worker-type1")), "router")
```

Insider the router

```
case Terminated(actorRef) =>
  actorRef.path.name match {
    case "type1" => //add type1 worker
    case "type2" => //add type2 worker
    case _ => //ignore
  }
```

Comment: Thanks ! Naming actor is the way to go. However, `actorRef.path.name match {` is the right way to get actor name from an `ActorRef`

Comment: @iwalktheline missed it some how. thanks for the correction.